# PHP Redirect with GET method

Tags: php, redirect

When people going to comment to my webpage, it will validate first if you are already login yet or not.

If not, then you have to log in first, what I try to doing here is that, after you log in. **you will redirect to last page when you try to give a comment**

So, I try to redirect page with GET method using PHP `header("Location:");`

This is my code:

HTML :

```
<form method="POST" action="addcomment.php">
    <textarea class="commentarea" name="comment" placeholder="your comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="Comment" />
</form>
```

**addcomment.php :**

```
header("Location:../loginfirst.php?location=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

it will send to loginfirst.php page, and the url will look like this :

http://localhost/ayojo/loginfirst.php?location=http://localhost/ayojo/product.php?p=test

After that, I try this code on **loginfirst.php :**

```
$_GET['location'] = $test;

    header('Location:'.$test);
```

Finally, I try log in then success. but, php header redirect me to the loginfirst.php not on the `$_GET['location']`.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: how on earth your http://localhost/ayojo will work on other machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use urlencode while setting header and assign value of $_GET['location'] to $test.

addcomment.php :

header("Location:loginfirst.php?location=".urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));

loginfirst.php :

$test = $_GET['location'];
header('Location:'.$test);

Comment: thanks dhi_m for your answer, it still not working. after i login, i will redirect to the loginfirst.php not on the last comment page.

Comment: Are you checking session in other pages? if yes make sure that session is set.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you declare the var $test as $_GET?
So in loginfirst.php:

```
$test = $_GET['location'];
```

You've got it the other way around now.

Comment: Aiken, thanks for answering. i try your method but still not working